# Trouble with a CSS nav Im building, hover wont work

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

I have two questions, in the NAV I´m making with CSS I use a div box as a sub-menu which comes up when hovering the menu. But I use also a CSS made triangle which is right underneath the menu. Here is the sample I use:

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t20sej/

Here are the two problems.

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
```

This is the div with the arrow

One: How could I center the triangle depending on the with of the list item? Cause the width is variable and I was looking to center that but haven’t found out how.

The div that displays after hover is the next

```
<div class="dropdown"> </div>
```

Two: When you hover over the menu the submenu comes up, BUT when you try to go to the submenu it closes cause of the margin I put so the triangle can be seen. Only if you hover through the triangle will the submenu stay open, but its kind of hard to figure that out and not really helpful at all. I need for the margin space to be hover also so the submenu wont disappear before getting to it.

Any ideas are welcome on both of them :D Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For the margin space and triangle issue, maybe you could put a transparent div (with padding) behind the triangle & menu.

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Comment: I sort of used your suggestion I just passed the styles for the background and the borders to an inner div, and the outer div used padding instead of margin. That made the trick. As for the arrow. I could not exactly center it, but with a div and a margin I could get really close :P Thanks for the suggestion. If anyone wants a nav. That one is really easy to customize. ITs all in the fiddle